# Yesterday, I Had Tears

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> > **Riddle Me This:**
>
> *I am filled with tears, 
>  But you won't see me cry; 
>  I've been known for years, 
>  But unexplored am I; 
>  Below, the light clears, 
>  But my face appears high. 
>  
>  Tomorrow, I'll have tears, 
>  Yet again, I will not weep; 
>  I have sounds without ears, 
>  And a bed without sleep. 
>  When the air volunteers, 
>  It joins the company I keep. 
>  
>  My tears are like yours, 
>  As they are salty, also blue, 
>  But a drop never pours, 
>  Down a pair of cheeks due, 
>  Unless you bury all fours, 
>  For when uncovered, that they do. 
>  
>  But what does "all fours" mean? 
>  Well, I've mentioned one with two. 
>  The clues are pretty clean, 
>  But there's one more I must tell you: 
>  My name is heard when seen, 
>  But damn the sound of W.*

This is a pretty long riddle, as I have not made a riddle in nearly a week. As for that, I have also provided a hint, but made it a little fun. The answer can be two different words, but they literally mean the exact same thing, so no need to fear — that is, if you can find the answer in the first place.

Let's *see*.

---

**Hint:**

> *You might also find some green, 
>  That looks like grass (this much is true). 
>  My pets are all ______, 
>  And my growing plants, ___.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> The Ocean

I am filled with tears, 
But you won't see me cry;

> Lots of water but it can't cry.

I've been known for years, 
But unexplored am I;

> We have always had them, but only explored like 3% or something.

Below, the light clears, 
But my face appears high.

> The ocean is deep and the light cannot reach beyond a certain layer.

Tomorrow, I'll have tears, 
Yet again, I will not weep;

> There will still be water in the ocean tomorrow and the next day.

I have sounds without ears, 
And a bed without sleep.

> Ocean sounds, and the ocean bed of sand?

When the air volunteers, 
It joins the company I keep.

> Maybe a hurricane.

My tears are like yours, 
As they are salty, also blue,

> Salt water, not fresh.

But a drop never pours, 
Down a pair of cheeks due,

> ?

Unless you bury all fours, 
For when uncovered, that they do.

> Indian, Pacific, Atlantic, and Arctic.

But what does "all fours" mean? 
Well, I've mentioned one with two.

> I am not sure but there are four oceans.

The clues are pretty clean, 
But there's one more I must tell you: 
My name is heard when seen, 
But damn the sound of W.

> Waves?

**Hint:**

You might also find some green, 
That looks like grass (this much is true). 
My pets are all ______, 
And my growing plants, ___.

> Fish and seaweed/kelp

Comment: Rot13(Lbh unir gur nafjre, fb jryy qbar! Ubjrire, fbzr bs gur ernfbavatf ner vapbeerpg. Bprnaf qb abg unir n cnve bs purrxf, fb hayvxr hf, gurve "grnef" pnaabg cbhe qbja gurz. Nyfb, vg jnf n fhecevfvat pbvapvqrapr ubj gurer ner sbhe bprnaf, orpnhfr V jnf abg ersreevat gb gurz! Ynfgyl, gur cneg jurer lbh zhfg svyy gur jbeqf va gur uvag nyfb eulzr.) Other than that, $(+1)$!

Comment: Well, anyways, you got it correct. Congratulations! $\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a weird interpretation:

> But a drop never pours,
> Down a pair of cheeks due,
> Unless you bury all fours,
> For when uncovered, that they do.

> The sea/ocean has no cheeks until you bury your own four. Your two cheeks and your two buttcheeks. When you rise out of the water and uncover them, the water runs down them.

Comment: This really shouldn't been a comment on the highly-voted accepted answer, not a new answer in itself. I realize that you can't comment yet but I have to flag this for deletion anyways, perhaps a moderator will convert it to a comment.