# Yesterday, I Had Tears (return)

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

Totally inspired by [Yesterday I had Tears](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68736/yesterday-i-had-tears) by @MrPie, thinking I had an answer, it led to a poem of it's own...

Riddle Me That:

> I'm filled with tears,
> You won't see me cry;
> I've been seen for years,
> Yet I have no eye.
>
> I'll always have tears,
> From sorrow I'm free;
> My father: The fire;
> My mother: The sea.
>
> My tears aren't like yours,
> Not salty, nor blue,
> Reminds you of wars,
> And look at their hue
> Though sadness they lack,
> My tears are all black.

(*response to @justforplaylists*)

> Though life I assist,
> A life I've not had 
> I've never been kissed
> I'm really not sad

(*response to @Prim3numbah*)

> You may even have me,
>  Or one tear or two;
>  Doubt that you love me
>  I never scared you

(*24hr clue*)

> If you have bought me,
>  My tears will be left,
>  They serve no purpose,
>  And leave me bereft

(*48hr clue*)

> My naming was cruel,
>  My value is low–
>  I sound like a jewel,
>  I've not much to show
>
>  You may now have guessed
>  That I'm treated like dirt
>  Please don't be depressed
>  It gives me no hurt

(*72hr 'give-away' clue*)

> If I am heated
>  It’s known that I grow
>  Being such treated
>  Could nigh pass for snow

---

I am wary of saying this but, to be honest, some of this is relies on poetic license. Truthfully,

> I do not *always* have tears.

and therefore

> I am not entirely *filled* with tears.

also

> The original last two lines of verse one were pulled because, while they followed the original MrPie poem, they are probable way too obscure and obfuscatory. 
>  *Below, the light clears,*
>  *My face to the sky.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the puzzle with hints you may be

> **[perlite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlite)** -  a silicous hydrated volcanic rock.

I'm filled with tears, You won't see me cry; I've been seen for years, Yet I have no eye.

> These are [Apache tears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_tears) which are often  embedded in gray perlite.

My father: The fire; My mother: The sea:

> You originate from the hydration of [obsidian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsidian) from lava.
>   *Prim3numbah identified a volcanic connection.*

My tears aren't like yours, My tears are all black:

> These Apache Tears are black pebbles of obsidian.

For some further hints

> Though life I assist, A life I've not had:
>  Perlite is used by gardeners to aerate compost, assisting plant growth.
>
>  If you have bought me, My tears will be left:
>  The black pebbles are mostly not included in bought perlite.
>
>  My naming was cruel, My value is low, I sound like a jewel:
>  Perlite sounds like Pearl, but it is inexpensive.
>
>  You may now have guessed, That I'm treated like dirt:
>  Perlite is mixed with soil for gardening purposes.
>
>  If I am heated, It’s known that I grow, Being such treated, Could nigh pass for snow:
>  When heated, trapped water vaporizes, and this causes the expansion of the material to many times its original volume. It becomes a brilliant white, due to the reflectivity of the trapped bubbles.

Comment: Amazing.. I was beginning to wonder if I wasn't being too obscure. @Tom to the rescue.

Answer (score 4):

Is this perhaps

> A volcano

*I'm filled with tears*

> Filled with lava, which eventually becomes black, after "crying".

*You won't see me cry*

> Not cry in the literal sense (like humans)

*I've been seen for years,
Yet I have no eye.*

> Volcano's been seen for a long time but don't have eyes.

*Below, the light clears,
My face to the sky*

> Below, filled with lava (light). A volcano face the sky.

*I'll always have tears,
From sorrow I'm free*

> A volcano will always have lava (tears) inside but never feel sorrow.

*My father: The fire;
My mother: The sea.*

> Not sure about this.. Lava is kinda like fire and volcanoes are mostly formed in oceans (submarine volcanoes?)

*My tears aren't like yours,
Not salty, nor blue*

> A volcano's "tears"(lava) are different from ours. Hot, not salty and not blue.

*Reminds you of wars,
And look at their hue
Though sadness they lack,
My tears are all black.*

> Explosions from wars reminds you of a volcano's eruption. They lack sadness and lava always become black (after cooling down).

And the last two lines;

*I do not always have tears.*

> A volcano doesn't erupt most of the times.. so it doesn't always have "tears"

And therefore

*I am not entirely filled with tears.*

> A volcano is not filled with lava all the way up to the top most of the time (except when it erupts).

Comment: It's a great interpretation, but unfortunately no cigar! I shall add an additional verse to provide a counter-example - and you know there was a stretch when you said 'Abg fher nobhg guvf'!!

Comment: Yes, I was not sure. Seemed it could be, some of the clues fitted better than others but that one was def a stretch.

Comment: I wouldn't say it was too much of a stretch. I was pretty positive this was it when I saw your answer. Particularly with recent events in Tonga and 'Yesterday' in the title.

Comment: I thought it might have been the answer, especially when I saw the "remind you of wars" line, but the "father and mother" part made me unsure. Not entirely given up though :)

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a stretch, but are you

> a poppy?

Reasoning

> "Tears" refer to poppy seeds. There are species of poppies that grow on shorelines, that grow after wildfires, and which are worn to commemorate WWI.

However

> These are all different species of poppies, and it doesn't make sense to have one or two poppy seeds.

Comment: Oh I so want to do a cbccl riddle poem now!  Still no cigar, but lovely imagery.

Comment: I added a counter-example for this ;-D.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> The fog

I'm filled with tears,
You won't see me cry;

> Fog is made of water, just like tears.

I've been seen for years,
Yet I have no eye.

> Fog is a common appearance you can see in most places and times.

I'll always have tears,
From sorrow I'm free;

> Where the fog has passed the ground will be wet.

My father: The fire;
My mother: The sea.

> Fog comes from when the sun (fire) warms up water (the sea) until it evaporates.

My tears aren't like yours,
Not salty, nor blue,
Reminds you of wars,

> In wargames where you cannot see the enemy's movement, it is hidden by "the fog of war."

And look at their hue
Though sadness they lack,
My tears are all black.

> When the fog has dampened the earth, it becomes black.

Comment: Ah, I wish I it had been that - I love your reading of the verses.  If you read the clues (especially Prim3numbah's, or the 24hr),  you will see that there is more to it than you have.